# How to take backup of amazon database(mysql)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, database-backups

I want to take backup of database from amazon by using linux command .
I am trying for

```
mysqldump --databases mydbname -v -h XXXXX.XXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u username -P 3306 -p > mydbname.sql
```

But it gives the error

mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'username'@'125.94.62.234' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Please help me out

Comment: So are you trying to connect remotely to your mysql server...i assume that your ip is `125.94.62.234` and that your create a user on your mysq server associated to that ip and then you create a rule to access the port 3306 to connect from the outside in your amazon configuration...

Comment: Does your user `username` has GRANTs in MySQL to read?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add your ip address in AWS security group

you can check your ip address by type in google "what is my ip".

TO add in AWS - you need to login in your AWS site

GOTO EC2 services
then goto - Security groups under Network / security

check your used security group and then click into inbound rule

Add new rule
Select Mysql Aurora / TCP / 3306 / Custom IP / your ip address.

After doing all this you can use below command

mysqldump -u  -p -h  databasename > backup.sql

hope this can help you